# CGRectOffset Causes Swiping The Wrong Way

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, frame, cgrect

Trying to be able to swipe away a cell and another view will show up. This is my code so far, but I am unable to see the rightView. Instead it limits me to seeing the leftView(I want the opposite...leftView does not even exist). Very confused with CGRects and CGRectOffsets. If you could correct my code that would be great. Thanks.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
[super layoutSubviews];

CGRect frame = self.bounds;
self.scrollView.frame = frame;
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width*2, frame.size.height);

self.centerView.frame = CGRectOffset(frame, frame.size.width, 0);
self.rightView.frame = CGRectOffset(frame, frame.size.width*2, 0);

[self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:self.centerView.frame animated:NO];
[self.scrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the centerView and rightView's offset to be `frame.size.width` and `frame.size.width*2` respectively. What you want is for the center to be `0` and the right view to be `frame.size.width`.

You are just moving your views over too much so the left `frame.size.width` number of pixels just dont have a view.